# Apache NiFi: How do I get a audit log of who logged into the UI?

Tags: apache-nifi

Whats a good way to determine who logged into the NiFi cluster?
Both failed and successful authentications report would be ideal.

One approach I can think of is to have the logs consolidated in one place then grep for certain API invocations.

What's the best practice in this regard.

I am on NiFi 1.9.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-user.log` file is where all actions taken on a NiFi instance are recorded. The severity/threshold of which messages are recorded is controlled by `$NIFI_HOME/conf/logback.xml`, and specifically the lines below:

```
<!--
    Logger for capturing user events. We do not want to propagate these
    log events to the root logger. These messages are only sent to the
    user-log appender.
-->
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.web.security" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.web.api.config" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.authorization" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.cluster.authorization" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.web.api.AccessResource" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
</logger>
```

You can set any of those values to `DEBUG` rather than `INFO` to get more verbose logging.

Example output:

```
2019-06-19 10:54:51,181 INFO [NiFi Web Server-20] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (<JWT token>) GET https://node1.nifi:9441/nifi-api/flow/current-user (source ip: 127.0.0.1)
2019-06-19 10:54:51,183 INFO [NiFi Web Server-20] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for cn=alopresto,ou=people,dc=nifi,dc=com
2019-06-19 10:54:51,232 INFO [NiFi Web Server-20] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (<JWT token>) GET https://node1.nifi:9441/nifi-api/flow/client-id (source ip: 127.0.0.1)
2019-06-19 10:54:51,232 INFO [NiFi Web Server-26] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (<JWT token>) GET https://node1.nifi:9441/nifi-api/flow/config (source ip: 127.0.0.1)
2019-06-19 10:54:51,235 INFO [NiFi Web Server-26] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for cn=alopresto,ou=people,dc=nifi,dc=com
2019-06-19 10:54:51,235 INFO [NiFi Web Server-20] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for cn=alopresto,ou=people,dc=nifi,dc=com
2019-06-19 10:54:51,261 INFO [NiFi Web Server-21] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (<JWT token>) GET https://node1.nifi:9441/nifi-api/flow/banners (source ip: 127.0.0.1)
2019-06-19 10:54:51,264 INFO [NiFi Web Server-21] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for cn=alopresto,ou=people,dc=nifi,dc=com
2019-06-19 10:54:51,290 INFO [NiFi Web Server-26] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (<JWT token>) GET https://node1.nifi:9441/nifi-api/flow/processor-types (source ip: 127.0.0.1)
2019-06-19 10:54:51,291 INFO [NiFi Web Server-26] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for cn=alopresto,ou=people,dc=nifi,dc=com
2019-06-19 10:54:51,293 INFO [NiFi Web Server-123] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (<JWT token>) GET https://node1.nifi:9441/nifi-api/flow/about (source ip: 127.0.0.1)
2019-06-19 10:54:51,295 INFO [NiFi Web Server-123] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for cn=alopresto,ou=people,dc=nifi,dc=com
2019-06-19 10:54:51,325 INFO [NiFi Web Server-123] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (<JWT token>) GET https://node1.nifi:9441/nifi-api/flow/controller-service-types (source ip: 127.0.0.1)
2019-06-19 10:54:51,326 INFO [NiFi Web Server-123] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for cn=alopresto,ou=people,dc=nifi,dc=com
```